# Making app compatible with tablets

Tags: android, sms, tablet, android-permissions, uses-feature

Well I have this app that have an option to read device sms and missed calls. This is not a needed feature, but its present. The problem is that I have this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS">
</uses-permission >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS">
</uses-permission >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
</uses-permission >
```

And I'm sure that some of them are making the app incompatible with tablets, so I tried to change it to:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="false">
</uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" android:required="false">
</uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" android:required="false">
</uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false">
</uses-feature>
```

But now the app wont show the sms when running in a phone. Is there anything else that I should include in order to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: why so? These options are available in tablets too, right!

Comment: Unfortunately not every tablet have those.

Comment: put the codings related to sms, contacts in try catch block, then, if they are not supported alternative ways could be done...

Comment: The issue is not the coding, is that the Play Store reads the `Manifest` to see what device it supports and as soon as it see that it needs `telephony` it wont show the app for tablets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  Some permissions imply features, but it isn't a 1-to-1 ratio.

The implied feature for SMS is:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Here is the list of all permissions that imply features:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it worked when Play Store upload my app.